# An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for windows authentication

Tags: sql-server

One of our SQL servers is configured to use both Windows and SQL Authentication, however, we are seeing the continues error "An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication" in the log. From SQL Management studio we are able to access the server using the same user credentials using SQL Authentication but when one of the applications is using the same user credentials to connect to the SQL server then we are getting the same error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the Server Properties through SSMS, under the `Security` tab? Can you also provide the Connection String being used by the application?

Comment: *"One of our SQL servers is configured to use both Windows and SQL Authentication"* ... *" "An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication" "* If you're seeing that error, your opening statement cannot be true.

Comment: What does `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly');` return?

Comment: The above query returns 0

Comment: I have added the requested Security tab screenshot

Comment: Are you utilizing any cross-server setups like clustering, alwayson, etc.?

Comment: No, we don't have any cross-server setups

Comment: Wait, how were those errors logged on `12/12/2019`? It's only the 10th today (or 11th in UTC+8 or more locations). Is your screenshot from the future?

Comment: The server is having the date as of 12/12/2019

Comment: *"The server is having the date as of 12/12/2019"* Why...? This sounds more and more like you have some other underlying problems. A server that (apparently) says it's in mixed authentication mode, but denies SQL logins, and thinks it's in the future has some unique problems, and I doubt we have the real picture here.

Comment: I do have the same other server having the same error which is having 10/12/2019

Comment: Looks like you are connecting to another server or another instance that is not configured to allow both auth modes.

Comment: try to connect your application to the DAC (using sa). it sounds extreme but given the circumstances, with servers in the future and what not.... it might be worth it a try. on a side note: is your application spamming connections? why so many attempts during a single minute?...and where is the username?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to restart the SQL Engine Service for the change to be applied. Whoever changed the authentication may not have restarted the service.

Comment: as commented above, SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly');  = 0,  both win&sql auths allowed (the serverproperty shows the current state)